# Alebgraic curve and Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, plane-curves

How do we prove that any smooth complex algebraic curve $C\subset\mathbb{P}^2$ is a Riemann surface?

Does there exist a complex version of the implicit function theorem?

Comment: I believe you mean $ C \subseteq \mathbb{CP}^{2} $.

Comment: Also, it’s important to distinguish between (i) the Zariski topology on $ \mathbb{CP}^{2} $ and (ii) the analytic topology on $ \mathbb{CP}^{2} $, which is the finest topology on $ \mathbb{CP}^{2} $ that makes the obvious projection mapping $ q: \mathbb{C}^{3} \to \mathbb{CP}^{2} $ continuous. When showing that $ C $ is a Riemann surface, you want to consider only the analytic topology and equip $ C $ with an atlas in that topology that is analytic.

Answer (score 1):

Take $(x:y:z)$ as the homogeneous co-ordinates on the projective plane. Then the subset of the curve where $x\ne0$ being open in  $C$ is again smooth. But this subset is embeddable as closed set in  $\mathbf{C}^2$: dehomogenize the equation taking $y/x, z/x$ as affine co-ordinates. This gives a co-ordinate patch. Similarly do for the other co-ordinates. Verification that transition between the patches are analytic follows from the fact these transition functions are rational functions with denominators not vanishing on the intersections.